# Sort tables with two elements

Tags: java, sorting

I want to make a sort in Java. In my object I have many element so I want to make this sort with power and model:

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product>,Serializable
{   
private int idProduct ;
private int power;
private String model;
private String  color;
[...]
@Override
    public int compareTo(Product o) {
        return String.valueOf(this.power).compareTo(String.valueOf(o.power));

    }
```

So how to make sort with power and model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will first sort on `power` and in case of a tie, will sort on `model`:

```
public int compareTo(Product that) {
  if(this.power != that.power) {
    return this.power < that.power ? -1 : 1;
  } 
  else {
    return this.model.compareTo(that.model);
  }
}
```

Or if you need to compare `power` lexicographically, do:

```
public int compareTo(Product that) {
  if(this.power != that.power) {
    return String.valueOf(this.power).compareTo(String.valueOf(that.power));
  } 
  else {
    return this.model.compareTo(that.model);
  }
}
```

Comment: nice, except `o` and `that` aren't the same word you know :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide which is the first thing to sort by, and which is the second.  Once you decide that, you simply implement the `compareTo` method like so:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Product o) {
    int result = this.model.compareTo(o.model);
    if (result == 0)
        return String.valueOf(this.power).compareTo(String.valueOf(o.power));
    else
        return result;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to change the `compareTo` method, you can write your own [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) like so:

```
public class ProductComparator implements Comparator<Product> {
    public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
        int result = p1.model.compareTo(p2.model);
        if (result == 0)
            return String.valueOf(p1.power).compareTo(String.valueOf(p2.power));
        else
            return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quicker but it gives a different sort order (e.g. 2 < 11 but "2" > "11")

Comment: Why convert power to a String in order to compare?  You could just write: result = this.power - o.power.

Comment: @Adamski look at @Simon's comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

CompareTo should return -1 when *this* is less than *o*, 0 when they are equal, and 1 when *this* is greater than *o*.

Presumably you're aiming to use model to sort the items with the same power, so you'd do something like:

```
int powerDiff=String.valueOf(this.power).compareTo(String.valueOf(o.power));  
if(powerDiff==0)  
  return String.valueOf(this.model).compareTo(String.valueOf(o.model));  
return powerDiff;
```

Comment: The contract for compareTo states that it should return a negative integer, 0 or a positive integer depending on the outcome (e.g. it doesn't have to return -1, it could return -100).

Answer (score 0):

Some additional points:

1) It is not necessary to convert power to a `String` in order to compare it.  You could do an integer based comparison:

```
int result = this.power - o.power;
if (result == 0) {
  result = this.model.compareTo(o.model);
}
```

**Note that this will produce a different sort order to the string-based comparison** though (e.g. "200" > "10000" whereas 200 < 10000).

2) You could further optimise your `compareTo` method by checking whether the object is being compared against itself:

```
public int compareTo(Product that) {
  int ret;

  if (this == that) { // Object is being compared against itself.
    ret = 0;
  } else {
    // Do full comparison.
  }

  return ret;
}
```

3) From the Comparator Javadoc:

> Caution should be exercised when using
>   a comparator capable of imposing an
>   ordering inconsistent with equals to
>   order a sorted set (or sorted map).

Your comparison method is only based on power and model whereas equality will be based on object identity unless you override the `equals` method.  Hence you may want to consider overriding `equals` (and `hashCode`) to make them consistent with `compareTo`.